# Set ImageBrush.ImageSource to Image in Windows 8 store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, imagebrush

I have an Image object in my C# code and I'd like to use it as ImageSource for ImageBrush.
Is there a way to do this?

In other words, I need something like this:

```
Image image = new Image();

image.source = GetBitmapImage();

//execute various image transforms here...

ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();

imageBrush.ImageSource = image; // this doesn't work
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `ImageSource` property is set to type of [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagesource). Therefore you must provide an object that derives from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource`.

Your object "image" is of type `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image` which is not derrived from the `ImageSource` type.

However, your method `GetBitmapImage()` returns a type of `ImageSource` so you can call the code below after you have finished your modifications.

`imageBrush.ImageSource = image.Source;`

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You already have `ImageSource` - it is your `GetBitmapImage()`, so you can use

```
 ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush(GetBitmapImage());
```

or use your image.source:

```
imageBrush.ImageSource = image.source;
```